# How to check Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler version?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler versions are [tightly coupled](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#which-version-on-cluster-autoscaler-should-i-use-in-my-cluster) to Kubernetes versions. How can I check what version of Cluster Autoscaler is deployed currently in my Kubernetes cluster?

Running `gcloud container clusters describe my-kube-cluster` does not return the Cluster Autoscaler version:

```
nodePools:
- autoscaling:
    enabled: true
    maxNodeCount: 12
    minNodeCount: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no endpoint in the cluster autoscaler that prints it's version, including `/health-check` and `/metrics`. The only place I could find that referenced a version number was [this line in the initialisation code](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/da224d4db9fc6269914e0cd1d662b923b2dc7789/cluster-autoscaler/main.go#L286), which you might find in the cluster autoscaler logs. Other than that I guess you could use the kubernetes API to query the cluster autoscaler Deployment resource image tag:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath="{..image}" -l app=cluster-autoscaler
```

Comment: Awesome solution with the logs. Great thinking and research - thank you!